# Search bar is searching for image source link, how can I make it search for a name instead?

Tags: javascript, html, filtering

I'm trying to use the list.js method to search for certain results from a gallery of images. At the moment, the search bar is using the image source link to search for results. Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div id="users">
    <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
        <ul class="list">

            <!-- Apple -->
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="name"><img src="img/Apple.jpg"></a>
            </li>

            <!-- Orange -->
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="name"><other src="img/Orange.jpg"></a>
            </li>

            <!-- Lemon -->
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/Lemon.jpg"></a>
            </li>

            <!-- Banana -->
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="other/Banana.jpg"></a>
            </li>
```

Javascript

```
var options = {
    valueNames: [ 'name' ]
};

var userList = new List('users', options);
```

When I type in lets say "img" it gives me Lemon, Orange and  Apple in the search results which I don't want to happen. I don't know what to do to make the search bar give me results of actual names (Just Apple, Banana, Orange, Lemon) instead of the whole image source link.

Comment: Wait I don't understand, what do you want me to correct? Do you want me to remove the link? All relevant code is in the post so i think it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I'm not sure what to call it but it's like a library to add a searching/sorting features to your code. Again, I don't really know what to call it. I decided to put in the link because its a lot of code to put in a post. Wanted people to know what I was using. EDIT: Anyway, I removed the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is happening because you have added the class name as search source but the tab with class name is a link which includes the image itself , try separating the image from the link or add a separate class to the image code
what I am trying to say is this :

```
<a class="x"> ....... </a>
```

when you search, it will return anything inside the tag(.....)
so you need to move the image part out of it or create a new searchable tab
try this:

```
<a href="#" ><img src="img/Apple.jpg"></a> <a class="name"> Image_Name </a>
```

or

```
 <a class="name">Image_Name </a> <img src="img/Apple.jpg">
```

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: It worked great, But now there's a pesky link in the way.

Comment: which one did you use ?

Comment: They both worked, the first one displays the link on the bottom and the second one displays it on the top of the image. I'm gonna use the second one. It's fine if It's not possible to hide the link, It'd be better if It is hidden but it's not unusable.

Comment: glad that it helped you :), try changing <a class="name">Image_Name </a> to <span class="name">Image_Name </span>  but please note that you wont be able to link the results